# Jboss fuse missing osgi.wiring.package

Tags: maven, jboss, jbossfuse

When I start my Jboss fuse server this error pops up

```
ERROR: Bundle cxf-basic [293] Error starting mvn:org.fusesource.example/cxf-basic/1.0-SNAPSHOT (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle cxf-basic [293]: Unable to resolve 293.0: missing requirement [293.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=META-INF.cxf)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))))
```

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle cxf-basic [293]: Unable to resolve 293.0: missing requirement [293.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=META-INF.cxf)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4002)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2045)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1299)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

my suspect is there's missing/conflicted version of osgi.wiring package, but how do I check?

Oh Hi guys, another update I finally got into my hawtio, the bundle gives me this error logs

[image]

I was able to do everything normally if I run the program as java application, but when I deploy to fuse this errors pops up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the JBoss FUSE version you are using?

The META-INF.cxf was exported by all-in-one cxf-bundle, however this was deprecated for very long time. We now use small CXF bundles for each module in CXF.

So the cxf-basic bundle shouldn't Import Package META-INF.cxf anymore if you wanna it works in the latest JBoss FUSE.

Freeman

Comment: Hi freeman thanks for the fast reply. I'm using 6.3.0. so quite latest.